# PandasNotImplementedError in Databricks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark-pandas

I'm using pandas in Databricks, with

`import pyspark.pandas as ps`

After reading two tables as a dataframe, `df` and `df_aux`, I'm executing the following line:

`index_list = df.loc[~df['Column_A'].isin(df_aux)].index`

But it raises the following error:

`` PandasNotImplementedError: The method `pd.Series.__iter__()` is not implemented. If you want to collect your data as an NumPy array, use 'to_numpy()' instead. ``

Any ideas on how to obtain the same variable `index_list` using pyspark.pandas?